# Nullpointer exception in fragment (initializing listview)

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments

Here's my code for trying to display a list in a `Fragment`, which as of now keeps reporting a `NullPointerException` whenever it tries to initialize the `ListView`:

```
public class PortfolioFragment extends ListFragment {

ListView l;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
List<String> list;

public PortfolioFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);                

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    list = MainActivity.globalArrayTest;
    l = (ListView) getView().findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    l.setAdapter(adapter);

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_portfolio, container, false);

}
```

I am getting an error at this line:

```
l = (ListView) getView().findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

Comment: post the logcat please

Comment: you should use the inflater to find your view. See @Raghunandan 's answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change to

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_portfolio, container, false);
l = (ListView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
return v;
```

You should have the below in xml

```
<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
```

Or override `onActivityCreated` and use `getListView()`

Also you can use the below as black belt commented this is better than the above.

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            l = getListView(); // since you extend ListFragment
}
```

Comment: getListView is the best solution in this case

Answer (score 3):

since you are extending `ListFragment` you should use `getListView()` instead of `findViewById` and `setListAdapter` should be called after `onCreateView` (inside `onActivityCreated`, for instance)

Answer (score 0):

This is another way to go about this, although I extend only Fragment

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
                                          Bundle SavedInstanceState) {

            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item, container, false);


            ListView itemList = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.itemListView);


     String[] items = {"Alpha", "Orange", "Pineapple", "Venus", "Echo", "Pent", "Mouse", 
                      "Phoenix", "Dent", "Sloppy"};


         ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(rootView.getContext(),
                      R.layout.text_row, items);

  itemList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(rootView.getContext(), 
                             R.layout.fragment_item, items));

    itemList.setAdapter(adapter);


    return (rootView);
}
```